# NSMutableURLRequest with multiple headers

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, rest, nsurlrequest

I'm trying to create a synchronous REST request to an API. The API uses HTTP Basic authentication, so in addition to sending an `Accept: application/json` header, I need to specify the `Authorization` header as well with my Base64-encoded username and password pair. When I use *just one header* the request executes just fine (either successfully authenticating me, or specifying my content format), but when I use both headers, it seems to ignore the `Authorization` line and returns "HTTP Basic access denied" (presumably a 401).

So I can't for the life of me figure out whats wrong. *I'm 100% sure my credentials are valid, because executing the request via  REST client works just fine.* I'm pretty new to Objective-C so I think perhaps there could be some kind of design pattern I'm not following. Is it valid to call `setValue:forKey` on an `NSMutableDictionary` multiple times like that? I also tried using `setValue:forHTTPHeader` on the request object with the same results.

Here's the code:

```m
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://foo.com/api/v1/bar"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request= [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSMutableDictionary *headers = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSURLResponse *urlResponse;
NSError *error;

[headers setValue:@"application/json" forKey:@"Accept"];
[headers setValue:@"Basic ..." forKey:@"Authorization"];

[request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];

NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request 
                                        returningResponse:&urlResponse 
                                                    error:&error];

NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData 
                                                 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@",responseString);
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the values to the request instead of replacing all header fields? I.e., instead of using `-setAllHTTPHeaderFields`, use `-addValue:forHTTPHeaderField:`.

Comment: Also, the canonical method for adding data to a dictionary is `-setObject:forKey:`.

Comment: And lastly, is the contents of `Authorization` an `NSString`?

Comment: Have you tried using the ASIHttpRequest library?

Comment: @Bavarious - Tried all of your suggestions (and I specify Authorization as an already-encrypted string literal just like I have it above) with no luck.

Comment: @яοвοτағτєяаււ - Yes, but wondering why I can't do something so simple without a third-party library.

Comment: I should note, as well, that I *WAS* able to get it working via an asynchronous call (using `NSURLCredential`, or whatever, as a response to an authentication challenge), however since I'm just starting out with Cocoa, I want to do it as simply and straightforwardly as possible. If what I'm trying to do is just not possible, that's okay, but I'd like a little explanation as to why so I understand these kind of limitations in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use:

```
[request addValue:@"Basic ..." forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

Which adds **another** header into the request instance.